# How to conserve all the columns in a groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, group-by

I have a df with some columns and I want to group the information in a column but keep the rest, specialy because I want to get the maximum value.

| ID | academic_level | sex | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 | 4 |

I would like to have the following:

| ID | academic_level | sex | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 | 4 |

I mean to group the id and get the maximum academic value and keep the rest of the variables

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmax()`, `loc` and `groupby` to get your desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'academic_level': [9, 1, 5, 7],
                   'sex': [1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'location': [3, 3, 4, 4]})

df_result = df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['academic_level'].idxmax()]
```

`df_result` holds:

```
   ID  academic_level  sex  location
0   1               9    1         3
3   2               7    2         4
```